# How do we combine two dataframes using one key ID while maintaining column names?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two different data sets:
df1

| date | location | earthquake | rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Feb-2022 | US. | 1. | 2. |
| 02-Feb-2022 | US. | 3. | 4. |
| 03-Feb-2022 | US. | 5. | 6. |

df2

| date. | location | earthquake | rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Feb-2022 | Canada | 7. | 8. |
| 03-Feb-2022 | Canada. | 9. | 10. |
| 04-Feb-2022 | US. | 11. | 12. |

I used

```
df1.merge(df2,how='inner',on='date')
```

output (not what i wanted)

| date | location_1 | earthquake_1 | rain_1 | location_2 | earthquake_2 | rain_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Feb-2022 | US | 1 | 2 | Canada | 7 | 8 |
| 03-Feb-2022 | US | 5 | 6 | Canada | 9 | 10 |

output (what i wanted)

| date. | location | earthquake | rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Feb-2022 | US | 1. | 2. |
| 01-Feb-2022 | Canada. | 7. | 8. |
| 03-Feb-2022 | US. | 5. | 6. |
| 03-Feb-2022 | Canada. | 9. | 10. |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matched values between two dataframes can be recognized as duplicates on target column (`date` in your case) after concatenation:

```
res_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
res_df = res_df[res_df['date'].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values('date')
```

---

```
           date location  earthquake  rain
0  01-Feb-2022       US            1     2
0  01-Feb-2022   Canada            7     8
2  03-Feb-2022       US            5     6
1  03-Feb-2022   Canada            9    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you simply want to concatenate the two dataframes

see the sample code below for a proposed solution

```py
In [25]: 
    ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {
    ...:         "date": ["01-Feb-2022"] * 3,
    ...:         "location": ["US"] * 3,
    ...:         "earthquake": [1] * 3,
    ...:         "rain": [2] *3,
    ...:     }
    ...: )
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {
    ...:         "date": ["01-Feb-2022"] * 3,
    ...:         "location": ["Canada"] * 3,
    ...:         "earthquake": [1] * 3,
    ...:         "rain": [2] *3,
    ...:     }
    ...: )
    ...: 
    ...: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Out[25]: 
          date location  earthquake  rain
0  01-Feb-2022       US           1     2
1  01-Feb-2022       US           1     2
2  01-Feb-2022       US           1     2
3  01-Feb-2022   Canada           1     2
4  01-Feb-2022   Canada           1     2
5  01-Feb-2022   Canada           1     2

In [28]: 
    ...: df["locations_per_date"] = df.groupby("date")["location"].transform("nunique")
    ...: 
    ...: mask = df["locations_per_date"] > 1
    ...: 
    ...: df = df[mask]
    ...:
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But what if I want dates where both US and Canada must match? Shouldn't I use inner merge?

Comment: You can add a post-processing step which keeps the records that have a more than 1 unique location per date


```df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df["locations_per_date"] = df.groupby("date")["location"].transform("nunique")

mask = df["locations_per_date"] > 1

df = df[mask]
```

Comment: I updated my solution above as well

Answer (score 0):

Using the intersection of the dates as filter:

```
keep = set(df2['date'])&set(df1['date'])

out = (pd.concat([df1[df1['date'].isin(keep)], df2[df2['date'].isin(keep)]])
         .sort_values(by='date', ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
          date location  earthquake  rain
0  01-Feb-2022      US.         1.0   2.0
1  01-Feb-2022   Canada         7.0   8.0
2  03-Feb-2022      US.         5.0   6.0
3  03-Feb-2022  Canada.         9.0  10.0
```

Another option with `concat` and reshaping:

```
(pd.concat([df1.set_index('date'), df2.set_index('date')], keys=[1, 2], axis=1)
   .dropna().stack(0).reset_index('date')
)
```